# Proof of equivalence between soundwaves and phonons in large wavelength limit (Ashcroft-Mermin, ch. 22)

Tags: condensed-matter, acoustics, phonons

In chapter 22, Ashcrof and Mermin argue that the normal modes of a harmonic crystal are not only formal but precisely equal to the large wavelength limit of acoustic phonons (which sounds, of course, logical).

In their equation (22.88), they arrive at 
$$
\rho \omega^2 \epsilon_{\mu}=\sum_{\tau \sigma \nu} c_{\mu \sigma\nu \tau} k_{\sigma}k_{\nu}\epsilon_{\tau} \;,
$$
where c is a tensor depending on the dynamical matrix given in their equation (22.79). It essentially is symmetric under exchange of the first two or last two indices or the exchange of the first and second pair. They claim that this symmetry is sufficient to show the equivalence of the above solution to the dispersion relation of phonons in the long wavelength limit
$$
\omega_s(k)= \sqrt{-\frac{1}{2M} \sum_{R} (k \cdot R)^2 D(R)} k \;.
$$
Not only do I fail to see how to argue this, but have I constructed a counter example by contracting both sides of the solution with an eigenvector (details are not important, since there are too many other assumptions to make it generic).

Landau Lifshitz, vol. 7 chapter III paragraph 23 deals with the same problem but does not remark the precise equivalence.

Has anybody figured out how to show the claimed result of Ashcroft and Mermin or can assure me that it is incorrect?

Comment: Without spending more time doing algebra than I'm willing to at this point, I looked over that section.  I'm quite happy with the development from 22.84 to 22.88 - it is straightforward.  Your real issue seems to be the how to relate this to the exposition leading up to 22.66.  The point is that, by specifying solutions of a particular form (22.87), you have already made the correspondence between the two approaches.  So, no, Ashcroft and Mermin are correct here.  I have no idea what your counter example looks like, but likely one of you assumptions is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Jon. I am also happy with the derivation of 22.88 and I agree that it has the same structure as 22.66. However, they claim that the specific form 22.79 of the tensor $c_{\mu\sigma\nu\tau}$ and its symmetries are sufficient to show that it is equivalent, i.e. can be brought to the same form.

Comment: However, if I insert 22.79 in 22.88, I get four terms which should be contracted with the appropriate indices with $k_{\sigma},k_{\nu},\epsilon_{\tau}$. The statement is correct that they should all coincide to the term $R_{\sigma}D_{\mu\tau}R_{\nu}$. This I can't show.